# escape a string for shell commands in Python

Tags: python, shell, escaping

I'm interested to escape a string in Python3.x, such as:

```
SOME_MACRO(a, b)
```

into...

```
SOME_MACRO\(a,\ b\)
```

... so that it can be passed to a program (not gcc in this case) as a define,

eg,

```
some_program -DSOME_MACRO\(a,\ b\)="some expression"
```

I would expect `shlex` would have this functionality but I didn't find how to do this and checked many similar questions already.

I don't mind to write some simple function to do this, but this seems the kind of thing Python would include.

**Note:** *the program I'm passing the argument to wont accept:*

```
-D"SOME_MACRO(a, b)"="some expression"
```

... it expects the first character to be an identifier.

Answer (score 14):

In Python 3.3 you can use [shlex.quote](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) to return a shell-escaped version of a string. It is the successor of [pipes.quote](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html#pipes.quote), which was deprecated since Python 1.6. Note that the documentation recommends this **for cases where you cannot use a list**, as suggested in another answer. Also according to the documentation, the quoting is compatible with UNIX shells. I can't guarantee that it will work for your case, but a quick test with `rm`, using `pipes` because I don't have Python 3.3:

```
$ touch \(a\ b\)
$ ls
(a b)

>>> import subprocess, pipes
>>> filename = pipes.quote("(a b)")
>>> command = 'rm {}'.format(filename)
>>> subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)

$ ls
$
```

Comment: This is awesome! It's not everyday that I learn something new about Python ;)

Comment: Also, for python2/3 compatibility: `from six.moves import shlex_quote`

Answer (score 1):

Doing it correctly means not having to worry about this. The shell has to worry about spaces and quotes and parens; Python does not.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([..., "-DSOME_MACRO(a, b)=some expression", ...], ...)
```

Comment: A bit more explanation of why you don't have to worry about it may be warranted.

Comment: You are pointing out that you don't always need to escape the string, this is fine and I knew that, but escaping the string remains a valid question (IMHO), you may be writing a shell script and not running the commands directly for example.

Comment: If you're writing a shell script then it's not a Python question.

Comment: @ideasman42, did you see shlex.quote() on Python 3.3? It's the successor of pipes.quote() to escape shell strings.

Comment: @Paulo Almeida, yes, but this is quite different escaping spaces for example doesn't work the same way, `shlex.quote("a b") --> "'a b'"` not `"a\ b"`

Comment: Both methods are the same to the shell.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, By "Writing a shell script", I mean generating a shell script from Python. (generating commands to run generally)

Comment: So then why are you using `subprocess`?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, there is no reference to `subprocess` in my question.

Comment: Not applicable to Python 2.7.6. With `shell=True`, that version expects that the command be given as a string, hence it expects it to be pre-formatted. If given as an array, `Popen` will use only the first argument in the array. Pretty crappy and undocumented behavior.