# Convert strings to bash escaped form

Tags: python, linux, bash, command-line-interface

**How to make normal strings (filenames in my case) to Linux CLI/bash escaped strings?**

Examples:

`"It's a great weather today" -> "It\'s\ a\ great\ weather\ today"`

`"Wind [Wine]" -> "Wind\ [Wine]"`

`"/Downloads/RPM's/" -> "/Downloads/RPM\'s/"`

I would like to know if there's an easier way to do that, as I am reading filenames in my python script and when I am forwarding them to a bash command, it's failing.

The problem is the number of files are too many and it won't be possible for me to rename or do string manipulation for them.

---

I am using Python 2.7 on a CentOS 7 System

Comment: Are you using `subprocess`? If the `bash` script is written correctly, you shouldn't need to. If the `bash` script *isn't* written correctly, there's no guarantee that doing this will help.

Comment: `foo="Wind [Wine]"; subprocess.call(["script.bash", foo])`. No escaping of `foo` should be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `shlex`, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html), it has arguments for `escape`, `qoutes` and `escapedqoutes`.

Comment: Thanks, I also find this link which was also helpful:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116465/escape-a-string-for-shell-commands-in-python